# Computing Strongly connected components using c programming language

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-algorithm

confused in this semgent of code
so these are two functions which i suppose to be buggy

```
void dfsloop1(int **g)
{
    int i;
    int temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<875714;i++)
    {
        temp = f[i];
        x[temp-1] = i;
    }
    for(i=875714;i>0;i--)
    {
        if(!explored[x[i-1]])
        {
            s = i-1;
            dfs1(g,x[i-1]);
        }
    }
}

void dfs1(int **g,int i)
{

    explored[i] = 1;
    leader[i] = s;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<a[i];j++)
    {
        if(!explored[(g[i][j]-1)])
        {
            dfs1(g,g[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

here explored array is keeping account of  node/vertex is checked or not if it is checked then say ith vertex is checked `then explored[i-1] = 1 else explored[i-1] = 0,a[i]` stores to how many vertex `i+1` th vertex is connected
for example the vertex no.1 is connected with 2,4,5 then `a[0]` will be 3, graph is passed in adjacency list and i have already run dfs on reverse graph and stored that magical numbering in f[i]
 using kosaraju's algorithm,now i am trying to run dfs on my original graph g
in x[i]
 i am storing f[i] in increasing order for example lets say on 9 vertex graph `f[0] = 7,f[1] = 3,f[2] = 1,f[4] = 2,f[5] = 5,f[6] = 9,f[7]=4,f[8] = 6 then x[0] = 2`(which is the index of smallest `f[i]),x[1] = 4,x[2] = 1` and so on.

if i left something or something is unclear please let me know.
Thanks

total number of vertices are 875714

i am new on stackoverflow so if i did anything wrong let me know

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also see: [ask].

Comment: What is your question? It's generally a good idea to do some range checking before using a variable as an array index.

Comment: i am using kosaraju's algorithm https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-iTBQCLcXUabHMxRmRGNmNzY1U is an example

Comment: i used malloc for storing numbers and checked if malloc returns null or not , my question is this function is giving segmentation fault

Comment: my full proram is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-iTBQCLcXUaR3BFMVdoSmRzZ2M and my input file for this program is here : https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fopen%3Fid%3D0Bw6QBmQ3-AHQWjkwYXhxd2V0dHc&h=ATOy9tAymRNc3WhSzil7itDLTWyte_O9SQplkYUbxGT1THtx8oH564ehcd3nIdlHyQ2Qaxg7duKQiwiRWnzWXRlaCYWjE04iD0EJM8SzpBb6TOMFXgD-BP08haTpjyS3-fCDSh32pwTXG0SA07rRtTYn8GxrhA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I viewed your code. I am assuming that you are new into this as your main function is jumbled with codes which is not actually convenient.
Two things:
 
1. You are dealing with pointers and also pointer of pointers.
2. You are consuming more than 10^5 integer memory for local variable/pointer.

I don't have much knowledge about pointers. However, as a contestant I used to have "Runtime Error" while declaring huge sized array locally. So, I think your problem lies in these two sections. Try to declare that pointers of pointer globally. See if it helps.

I am giving you a link of the SCC algorithm.
e-maxx: https://e-maxx-eng.appspot.com/graph/strongly-connected-components.html

and my implementation of scc:
https://bitbucket.org/techboy_zero/programming-and-software-development/src/035560584ce7ab7e0a3f6ab5ae1406095bd39b62/Programming%20Contest%20Algorithms/Graph%20Theory/Strongly_Connected_Component.cpp

Though, mine is in c++. Just see the dfs and kosaraju functions. If you have any problem understanding keywords, search in cplusplus.com. If don't understand the mechanism then feel free to ask me.